# Call InterSystem Cache.exe from cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, intersystems-cache

I am trying to build the Cache database and calling the command

```
echo do ##class(SYS.Database).DismountDatabase("%CACHE_DIR%\CODE") Halt  EOT | %CACHE_DIR%\bin\cache.exe -s %CACHE_DIR%\mgr -U %SYS
```

But after that immediately displays a message:

> Username:
>
> Password:
>
> Access Denied

How to pass parameters(username, password) to cache.exe in bat file?

I haven't found --help or something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
%CACHE_DIR%\bin\csession CACHE20172 -U %SYS "##class(SYS.Database).DismountDatabase(""%CACHE_DIR%\CODE"")"
```

Comment: Found similar question here https://community.intersystems.com/post/csession-class-command-windows-machine